# I have error Datalife engine panel diskfreespace

Tags: php, diskspace, datalife-engine

When website change PHP version 8.0 or 8.1 DLE panel display error and when I change php 7.4 everything is ok how can i fix this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFeRx.jpg)

I deleted this code line in main.php and panel home page fix but I think it is necessary

Comment: Contact your host, that function might be disabled in the server's php.ini. You can also contact the DLE developers to find out if it's necessary.

Comment: could you add an image description, please?

Comment: I contacted my hot and problem solved. https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFeRx.jpg